# Android - Fingerprint Enrollment

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

I would like to create an android native application for the devices supporting the fingerprint hardware,for enrolling/validating/uploading the fingerprint using my application.

As far as I researched ,Android introduced Fingerprint hardware support from **Android 6.0** but only allows to capture fingerprint using in-built **settings** application.

Also, the API is limited only to authenticate one or more already enrolled fingerprint in the device settings.

How can I  enroll/validate/upload the fingerprint without using device settings ?

**Update:**

As Michael said, there is no access to capture the Fingerprint as an app developer.

In this case , I would prefer to connect an external Fingerprint scanner through OTG cable.After some more research, I found [SecuGen SDK for Android](http://www.secugen.com/products/sdk_pro.htm#android).However,the Android supported SecuGen Fingerprint scanner has to be purchased in order to use this SDK.

Please let me know if anybody have tried SecuGen and suggesting me to use it or tried some other way and found the solution.

Comment: Device manufacturers are required to ensure that raw images and processed fingerprint features never leave the sensor hardware or trusted memory. So such data is not available to you as an app developer.

Comment: Is there any third party SDK you can prefer to accomplish the requirement ?@Michael

Comment: The library or API you use doesn't matter, because the data you want is not accessible to applications or even the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed E-attendance system and many more apps using secugen's fdx library with secugen fingerprint machine on android. working perfectly with great functionalities.

```
Note: Secugen's fingerprint library for android development is free to download from:
```

http://www.secugen.com/download/sdkrequest.htm

Comment: Thanks . I will try with Secugen :-)

Comment: Hi @Teerath can you help me on this , how i can implement this with my app.